# How can I get the unique characters from a string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to get the unique characters from a string in Oracle?

Lets say I have a column with data

```
CCCXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

and I want to return `'CX'` as the list of unique characters.

likewise: aaaabbbccccdddaaa ==> abcd , HelloO ==> HeloO

Order is important, I want them to be in the same order as they first appear in the string.

Is there any way to do it without using stored procedure?

Edit: add more examples

Comment: You asked about **character** but have given 2 chars as a result example.

Comment: You really _shouldn't_ be doing this. If you _ever_ find yourself manipulating things smaller than a complete column, you're almost certainly doing it wrong (and efficiency will suffer).

Comment: what's the real use case for that?

Comment: @zerkms, I've edited the question to hopefully make it clearer. I think what's needed is the list of unique characters in the string, in the order they first appear.

Comment: I think if it allows user-defined function like java written,then there is not any difficulty.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR('CCCCXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC', '^(.)\1*.'), -2, 2) RESULT
FROM DUAL;
```

It returns `CX`

Here is another solution:

```
Select Replace (Wm_Concat (C), ',', '')
From
  (Select Substr ('CCCXCCCXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC', Rownum, 1) C,
    Min (Rownum) Rn
  From Dual
    Connect By Rownum <= Length ( 'CCCXCCCXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC')
  Group By Substr ( 'CCCXCCCXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC', Rownum, 1)
  Order By Rn
  ) X;
```

It returns all the unique chars in order of their occurence. Btw, yes, it looks horrible

Comment: REGEXP_SUBSTR how does it work out the result in this case? the REGEX using here is stunning.

Comment: great! I would +2 if I can. :-)

Comment: updated the question, the regex doesn't really working (you substring so it only show the last 2 char), the second query is working but if the last character is not repeated, it will cut the last character (`aabbccddeeaaXCSDAA ==> abcdeXCSDA`, but `aabbccddeeaaXCSDA ==> abcdeXCSD`).
I think you must change the `<` to `<=` so it doesn't cut the last char.

Comment: Did everyone that up-voted that first solution even bother to test it with a different string? It fails miserably. Throw a D into the middle and it still returns CX. Put a D at the beginning and it returns DC. If I could, I would down-vote this.

Answer (score 0):

Other solution which works for me:

```
-- First, create a custom collection type (nested table type) to hold the unique characters:
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE char_list AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(1);

-- Next, create a pipelined function that splits the input string into unique characters and returns them as a collection:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_string(input_string VARCHAR2) RETURN char_list PIPELINED IS
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..LENGTH(input_string) LOOP
        PIPE ROW (SUBSTR(input_string, i, 1));
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END split_string;
/

-- Finally, use the pipelined function to list the unique characters in a string:
SELECT DISTINCT COLUMN_VALUE AS unique_character
FROM TABLE(split_string('YourInputStringToBeOrNotToBe'))
ORDER BY 1;
```