# How to find count and names of distinct characters in string in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, stringtokenizer, string-aggregation

I'm quite new to PL/SQL and I need to get the names and count of the distinct characters in a string. E.g. if I have a string `str="helloexample"`, I need to get output of distinct characters in `str`, i.e. `heloxamp`.

How can I do this?

Comment: I also tried WM_CONCAT but it is giving an invalid identifier error.

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working ?

Comment: There isn't a built-in function for that. You need to write some PL/SQL code yourself.

Comment: Show us your code what you have done till yet, so we'll be in a better position to help

Comment: It has been already answered. Here it [is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226303/how-can-i-get-the-unique-characters-from-a-string-in-oracle)

Comment: What version of Oracle you are using?

Comment: You need to combine two techniques: string tokenization (to get the individual characters) and string aggregation (to put them together again).  There are a variety of different solutions open to you, which will depend on your version of Oracle.

Comment: @RJ Yes, the second solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226303/how-can-i-get-the-unique-characters-from-a-string-in-oracle works perfectly. I just tried to make the solution myself, but the result would look very similar to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression as follows:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
     str        VARCHAR2(20):='helloexample';
     str_length NUMBER;
     c          VARCHAR2(20):=NULL;
     d          NUMBER;
BEGIN
     str_length:=LENGTH(str);
     FOR i IN 1..str_length
     LOOP
          IF regexp_instr(c,SUBSTR(str,i,1))>0 THEN
               NULL;
          ELSE
               c:=c||SUBSTR(str,i,1);
          END IF;
     END LOOP;
     dbms_output.put_line(c);
END;
```

the answer would be:

```
heloxamp
```

Comment: But it is better use query that already answered someone.

SELECT REPLACE (Wm_Concat (C), ',', '')
FROM
     (SELECT SUBSTR ('helloexample', Rownum, 1) C,
          MIN (Rownum) Rn
     FROM Dual
          CONNECT BY Rownum <= LENGTH ( 'helloexample')
     GROUP BY SUBSTR ( 'helloexample', Rownum, 1)
     ORDER BY Rn
     ) X;

Answer (score 0):

if WM_CONCAT isnt working for you, you can use this trick:

```
select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, str)).extract('//text()'), ',') as output
  from (select substr(str, level, 1) str, level l,
               row_number() over (partition by substr(str, level, 1) 
                                      order by level) rn
          from (select 'helloexample' str  from dual) d
        connect by level <= length(str)
        order by level)
 where rn = 1;


SQL> select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, str)).extract('//text()'), ',') as output
  2    from (select substr(str, rownum, 1) str, level l,
  3                 row_number() over (partition by substr(str, rownum, 1) order by level) rn
  4            from (select 'helloexample' str  from dual) d
  5          connect by level <= length(str)
  6          order by level)
  7   where rn = 1;

OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
heloxamp
```